Focus-visible outline is cut off by parents overflow-x: auto;
I have a container of buttons that is scrollable on the x-axis, and that has focus-visible styles for accessibility that displays an outline which overflows the container and is therefore cut off. I want the outline to still be visible even though it goes out of bounds of the container. Any tips on how to achieve this?
Current: 
Desired: 
Code:
.shortcuts {
 overflow-x: auto; 
}

.shortcut:focus-visible {
 outline: 0.125rem solid #9b0600;
 outline-offset: 0.125rem;
 z-index: 1;
}


Please include a [mre] of the problem, including the HTML that these styles are applied to.

I think I have included what’s relevant here.

The fact that you've turned down an answer because it breaks a layout that the answerer can't see in the example suggests otherwise.

CSS outlines exist outside of the box model so they will be cut off by default if the overflow is hidden. One fix for this is to use margin on the button with the outline to account for the space taken up by the outline.
Eg:
button {
  border: 2px solid;
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
.btn-outline-fix {
   margin: 4px; /* 2px outline + 2px offset */
}

Full code example here: https://codepen.io/Koda_pig/pen/emOJqyj

That is not an option unfortunately since that would break the design. But thank you for the suggestion!

Without providing more information, you're not going to get a helpful answer :)
